# How to disable game alerts from RDR2 on PS4?

Tags: ps4, red-dead-redemption-2

I keep getting notifications from Red Dead Redemption 2, about new clothing options or things that I have absolutely no interest in. I don't really play this game any more. How can I disable them?

I unchecked the "Game Alerts" option in settings months ago, but that doesn't seem to be the right option because they still pop up.